# How to generate crypto wallet addresses for one time payment that are connected to a centralized wallet

Tags: python, bitcoin, pycrypto, bitcoin-testnet, bitcoinlib

I've been trying to build something like coinbase-commerce that could generate a new wallet address for every transaction that could be connected to a centralised wallet using python

Comment: You have been trying? Show us your code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using pywallet since I'm using python. Still, I faced some errors which I thought it was due to my machine then tried it on another machine but had to move on due to I have limited time to fix bugs, then tried using bitcoinlib but later resolve to use py_crypto_hd_wallet which had all I need.